# How to get article text by article ID in Joomla?

Tags: php, joomla

I want to get article text by passing article ID from the joomla template.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simple, providing you sending an article id with post/get and using variable "id" as its number:

```
$articleId = JRequest::getInt('id');
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();

$sql = "SELECT fulltext FROM #__content WHERE id = ".intval($articleId);
$db->setQuery($sql);
$fullArticle = $db->loadResult();

if(!strlen(trim($fullArticle))) $fullArticle = "Article is empty ";
```

EDIT: to get articleId from anywhere:

```
$articleId = (JRequest::getVar('option')==='com_content' && JRequest::getVar('view')==='article')? JRequest::getInt('id') : 0;
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to get article text by passing article ID from joomla template?

Comment: articleId = JRequest::getInt('id');

Comment: or if you wanted to use a fixed article id, use template parameters: http://docs.joomla.org/Template_parameters

Comment: Can yoг hint me how to get the text until the cut, pls ?

Answer (score 7):

try this technique:

```
$article = JControllerLegacy::getInstance('Content')->getModel('Article')->getItem($articleId);
echo $article->introtext;
```

Comment: It works as long your are accessing the article content from another article. But once you are in the template code, it stop working

Answer (score 7):

Get article text by article ID in Joomla 2.5 (3 will work also according docs) plugins:

```
$article =& JTable::getInstance("content");
$article->load($id);
$content = '<h3>'. $article->get("title").'</h3>';
$content .= $article->get("introtext"); // introtext and/or fulltext
```

And article id is got from component/plugin parameters for example:

1. From inside own component:

   ```
   $app = JFactory::getApplication();
   $params = $app->getParams();
   $param = $params->get('terms_article_id');
   ```
2. From other component:

   ```
   $params = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_mycom');
   $id = $params->get('terms_article_id');
   ```
3. Get Module Parameter from template's php file:

   ```
   $module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_mymodule');
   $params = new JRegistry($module->params); // or $mymoduleParams if few used
   $id = (int) $headLineParams['count'];
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Joomla has the default script for getting content from sql table.

Here article (#__content)

To Get Article Id:

```
$articleId = (JRequest::getVar('option')==='com_content' && JRequest::getVar('view')==='article')? JRequest::getInt('id') : 0;
```

To get Article content:

```
$table_plan         = & JTable::getInstance('Content', 'JTable');
$table_plan_return  = $table_plan->load(array('id'=>$articleId));
echo "<pre>";print_r($table_plan->introtext);echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: this solution worked for me, even by accessing article context from a template php

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla 4/5:

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;

$app = Factory::getApplication();
$factory = $app->bootComponent('com_content')->getMVCFactory();
$model = $factory->createModel('Article');
$article = $model->getItem($id);

echo $article->introtext; // or fulltext
```