# Request Variables in Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla1.7

I am new to Joomla. I am trying to write a module which would fetch and display the contents from database.
Now for fetching the contents from database, I need to get the current article id and category id of the current article.

I am able to get the id with article title append using JRequest::getVar('id');
ex : 16:abc-def-article-title.

I can sub-string the id out of it but I think there would be a better place of achieving it ?
And also I need to get the category id as well.

Also please let me know how can I see what all variables does  JRequest::getVar(') holds.
Many Thanks !!

Comment: try here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219876/how-to-get-article-text-by-article-id-in-joomla

Comment: Which version of Joomla! do you use?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I don't seen tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, try extract article id by method `getInt()`:

```
JRequest::getInt('id', 0);
```

It's more safely, then `getVar()`.

Then, to get category id, you can use this code in module file:

```
jimport('joomla.application.component.model');
$articlesModel = JModel::getInstance('ContentModelArticle');

$articleId = JRequest::getInt('id', 0);
$article = $articlesModel->getItem($articleId);
$categoryId = $article->catid;
```

Using Joomla! built-in models instead direct SQL queries is best way to understanding Joomla architecture and writing safety applications that will be easily maintained in the future.

Note: code samples are actually only for Joomla 2.5 (probably and for 1.6, 1.7, but i don't shure).

Comment: This is great, though throws a fatal error if you're on a category/blog listing page.  Where did you find this code, haven't been able to find anything close to this and it would be super useful.